# Globally check value in mock

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have a mock that represents an API wrapper.

```
class MockApiWrapper : public ApiWrapper {
    public:
        MockNrfWrapper();
        virtual ~MockNrfWrapper();
        MOCK_METHOD1(api_do, void(int param));
};
```

Lets assume that `api_do` should never be called with `param = 0`. Since I use this mock "everywhere", I would like to append an assertion/expect to each call made to `api_do`. Example:

```
void MyClass::InvalidCallsToApi(void) {
    // api->api_do(0);  // Fails "global assert"
    // api->api_do(1);  // Fails by specific test
    api->api_do(2);     // Valid call
}
TEST(MyTestCase, FirstTest) {
    // Mock always checks that api_do is not called
    // with argument of 0
    EXPECT_CALL(api, api_do(Ne(1));
    uut->InvalidCallsToApi();
}
```

I tried doing this with an `ON_CALL` and `Invoke` in the constructor, but either it was overridden by the added EXPECT in the test, or I got compilation error (couldn't do ASSERT or EXPECT in invoked call).

I hope my problem statement is clear. Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: Is your mock a global object? Or do you create one for each test?

Comment: I create one for each test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've came up with one solution, it's not the nicest, but acceptable IMO.

**Code:**

```
struct BInterface {
    virtual void foo(int) = 0;
};

struct BMock : public BInterface {
    MOCK_METHOD1(foo, void(int));
    BMock() {
        ON_CALL(*this, foo(0))
                .WillByDefault(::testing::InvokeWithoutArgs([](){ADD_FAILURE() << "This function can't be called with argument 0";}));
    }
};

void testedMethod(int a) {
    BInterface* myB = new BMock;
    myB->foo(a);
    delete myB;
}

TEST(myTest, okCase) {
    testedMethod(1);
}

TEST(myTest, notOkCase) {
    testedMethod(0);
}
```

**Explanation:**
We add a default action to `BMock`, for every call of `foo` method with argument `0`.
In this action, we call a lambda, which uses GTest macro `ADD_FAILURE()` to generate a non-fatal fail - equivalent of `EXPECT_*` macros. You can use `FAIL()` instead for a fatal failure like in `ASSERT_*` macros.

We use `ON_CALL` macro in mock's constructor, which allows to avoid calling it with every other mock object.

**Limitations:**
The same trick won't work with `EXPECT_CALL` for example - I don't know GMock implementaion, but I assume `EXPECT_CALL` requires a fully initialized object.

A call with matcher that accepts `0` will still pass (i.e. `EXPECT_CALL(myB, foo(::testing::_));`, but that's the case in every other GMock expectations. GMock will always shadow older expectations when newer ones are encountered. You have to create your expectations in such a way that they won't override the previous expectations.
Adding `.RetiresOnSaturation()` to all your `EXPECT_CALL` will make sure that calls are forwarded to default action (set by `ON_CALL`), when they are not interesting.
Custom matchers will be helpful in cases when there are multiple disallowed values.

```
MATCHER(IsValidApiArg, ""){return arg == 0 || arg == 1;}

ON_CALL(*this, api_foo(!IsValidApiArg)
        .WillByDefault(::testing::InvokeWithoutArgs([](){ADD_FAILURE();}));

EXPECT_CALL(myMock, api_foo(IsValidApiArg));
```

---

*Note:* I still can't believe that GMock doesn't provide a default action for simply generating a failure. Perhaps you can find something better suitable deep in documentation.
You can also create a custom action for that, to avoid all that `Invoke` and lambdas.

Comment: This works very well! Since I'm having the constructor in a separate source file it keeps the bloat out of the mock interface/header as well. I can write an `EXPECT_CALL(myMock, api_foo(_))` and it will make sure that the function _is_ called. If I call it with an invalid value, the mock generates the failure. I used `::testing::AnyOf(...)` for checking multiple values.